# Ruby: Does NET::LDAP plus start_tls support certificate validation?

Tags: ruby, ssl, ldap, starttls

I am reading documents regarding NET::LDAP with TLS. But I could not find any mentioning regarding enforcing certificate validation with start_tls. The sample code is attached below.

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new :host => params["host"],
                     :base => params["base_dn"],
                     :encryption => :start_tls,
                     :port => params["port"],
                     :auth => { :username => params["bind_dn"],
                                :password => params["bind_pw"],
                                :method => :simple
                              }
```

The document here "http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/Net/LDAP.html#method-i-encryption" mentions there is no SSL certificate validation for simple_tls. But there is no information regarding start_tls.

Answer (score 0):

no, I checked the latest 0.6.1 version, this functionality is still missing.
simple_tls is actually LDAPS which usually on port 636.